# linq combine results from two tables to one select new statment?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

With the following query how to I change that I dont have two sets of fields in the select new I want the information going into one set of columns not having two and a type field to say if its a traineeevent or a cpd event ?

```
    List<EmployeeCPDReportRecord> employeeCPDRecords = new List<EmployeeCPDReportRecord>();
    string employeeName;
    var q =  from cpd in pamsEntities.EmployeeCPDs
             from traineeEvent in pamsEntities.TrainingEventTrainees
             join Employee e in pamsEntities.Employees on cpd.EmployeeID equals e.emp_no
             join TrainingEventPart tEventPart in pamsEntities.TrainingEventParts on traineeEvent.TrainingEventPartId equals tEventPart.RecordId
             where (cpd.EmployeeID == id) && (startDate >= cpd.StartDate && endDate <= cpd.EndDate) &&
                    (traineeEvent.EmployeeId == id)
                    && (traineeEvent.TraineeStatus == 1 || traineeEvent.TraineeStatus == 2)
                    && (tEventPart.CPDHours > 0 || tEventPart.CPDPoints > 0)
                    && (cpd.CPDHours > 0 || cpd.CPDPoints > 0)
                   || traineeEvent.StartDate >= startDate
                    || traineeEvent.EndDate <= endDate

              orderby cpd.StartDate



             select new
                {
                    surname = e.surname,
                    forname1 = e.forename1,
                    forname2 = e.forename2,
                    EmployeeID = cpd.EmployeeID,
                    StartDate = cpd.StartDate,
                    EndDate = cpd.EndDate,
                    CPDHours = cpd.CPDHours,
                    CPDPoints = cpd.CPDPoints,
                    Description = cpd.Description,                            
                    TrainingStartDate = tEventPart.StartDate,
                    TrainingEndDate = tEventPart.EndDate,
                    TrainingCPDHours = tEventPart.CPDHours,
                    TrainingCPDPoints = tEventPart.CPDPoints,
                    TrainingEventDescription = tEventPart.Description

                };


    if (q != null)
        {
            Array.ForEach(q.ToArray(), i =>
            {

                   if (ContextBase.encryptionEnabled)
                    employeeName = ContextBase.Decrypt(i.surname) + ", " + ContextBase.Decrypt(i.forname1) + " " + ContextBase.Decrypt(i.forname2);
                else
                    employeeName = i.surname + ", " + i.forname1 + " " + i.forname2;

               if (i.TrainingStartDate !=  new DateTime(1900, 1, 1))

                   employeeCPDRecords.Add(new EmployeeCPDReportRecord(employeeName, Convert.ToDateTime(i.StartDate), Convert.ToDateTime(i.EndDate), Convert.ToDecimal(i.CPDHours), Convert.ToDecimal(i.CPDPoints), i.Description,i.t,i.EndDate,Convert.ToDecimal(i.CPDHours),Convert.ToDecimal(i.CPDPoints),i.Description,"L&D"));
               else
                   employeeCPDRecords.Add(new EmployeeCPDReportRecord(employeeName, Convert.ToDateTime(i.StartDate), Convert.ToDateTime(i.EndDate), Convert.ToDecimal(i.CPDHours), Convert.ToDecimal(i.CPDPoints), i.Description, i.StartDate, i.EndDate, Convert.ToDecimal(i.CPDHours), Convert.ToDecimal(i.CPDPoints), i.Description, "Employee CPD"));



         });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
List<EmployeeCPDReportRecord> employeeCPDRecords = new List<EmployeeCPDReportRecord>();

var q = ( from cpd in pamsEntities.EmployeeCPDs
                     from traineeEvent in pamsEntities.TrainingEventTrainees
                     join Employee e in pamsEntities.Employees on cpd.EmployeeID equals e.emp_no
                     join TrainingEventPart tEventPart in pamsEntities.TrainingEventParts on traineeEvent.TrainingEventPartId equals tEventPart.RecordId
                     where (cpd.EmployeeID == id) && (startDate >= cpd.StartDate && endDate <= cpd.EndDate) &&
                            (traineeEvent.EmployeeId == id)
                            && (traineeEvent.TraineeStatus == 1 || traineeEvent.TraineeStatus == 2)
                            && (tEventPart.CPDHours > 0 || tEventPart.CPDPoints > 0)
                            && (cpd.CPDHours > 0 || cpd.CPDPoints > 0)
                           || traineeEvent.StartDate >= startDate
                            || traineeEvent.EndDate <= endDate

                      orderby cpd.StartDate
                     select new EmployeeCPDReportRecord
                        {
YourEmployeColumnName=(ContextBase.encryptionEnabled==true?ContextBase.Decrypt(e.surname) + ", " + ContextBase.Decrypt(e.forname1) + " " + ContextBase.Decrypt(e.forname2):e.surname + ", " + e.forname1 + " " + e.forname2), 
YourEmployeeCPDColumnName=(i.TrainingStartDate !=new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)?"L&D":"Employee CPD")    
                            surname = e.surname,
                            forname1 = e.forename1,
                            forname2 = e.forename2,
                            EmployeeID = cpd.EmployeeID,
                            StartDate = cpd.StartDate,
                            EndDate = cpd.EndDate,
                            CPDHours = cpd.CPDHours,
                            CPDPoints = cpd.CPDPoints,
                            Description = cpd.Description,                            
                            TrainingStartDate = tEventPart.StartDate,
                            TrainingEndDate = tEventPart.EndDate,
                            TrainingCPDHours = tEventPart.CPDHours,
                            TrainingCPDPoints = tEventPart.CPDPoints,
                            TrainingEventDescription = tEventPart.Description

                        }).ToList<EmployeeCPDReportRecord>();
```